# Iterating through array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, swap

I have an array of bools and now I want to swap those entries for numbers.

```
False => 0
True => 1
```

I have written two different pieces of code and I would like to know, which one is better and why. This is not so much about actually solving the problem, as about learning.

```
arr = [[True,False],[False,True],[True,True]]

for i,row in enumerate(arr):
    for j,entry in enumerate(row):
        if entry:
            arr[i][j] = 1
        else:
            arr[i][j] = 0
print(arr)
```

And the second approach:

```
arr = [[True,False],[False,True],[True,True]]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if arr[i][j]:
            arr[i][j] = 1
        else:
            arr[i][j] = 0    
print(arr)
```

I read that there are ways to do this with importing `itertools` or similar. I am really not a fan of importing things if it can be done with “on-board tools”, but should I rather be using them for this problem?

Comment: Definitely option A; iterating over `range(len(...))` isn't pythonic.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the answer I was looking for !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's define your array:

```
>>> arr = [[True,False],[False,True],[True,True]]
```

Now, let's convert the booleans to integer:

```
>>> [[int(i) for i in row] for row in arr]
[[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Alternatively, if we want to be more flexible about what gets substituted in, we can use a ternary statement:

```
>>> [[1 if i else 0 for i in row] for row in arr]
[[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: Beat me to it and much more elegant, I just did `[(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x])(i) for i in foo]` - I can't much say why my brain shutdown so hard and I didn't just do what you did :) end of the day on a friday must be

Comment: Maybe `int(bool(i))` rather than the ternary?

Comment: John1024. Thank you very much for also adding in the last part. Because later on I might want to use some other symbols instead of 1 and 0 :D

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stay with a for-loop (e.g. because you want to mutate the existing array instead of creating a new one), you should simplify the code.

I would first simplify the outer loop by removing the indexing (there is no need for it since it's even easier to modify a row than a nested array):

```
for row in arr:
    for j, entry in enumerate(row):
        if entry:
            row[j] = 1
        else:
            row[j] = 0
```

these kinds of simple if statement can often be simplified by using an if expression:

```
 row[j] = 1 if entry else 0
```

but in this case we can do even better. `bool` is a subclass of `int` (ie. all `bool`'s are `int`'s), and `True` and `False` are defined to be exactly `1` and `0` respectively -- if you scroll down to the specification section of PEP 285 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) you'll see that that equivalence is not accidental but very much by design.

We can therefore use the `int` constructor to grab the underlying integer values[*], since `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`, the if-expression can be simplified to:

```
row[j] = int(entry)
```

[*] technically this is an explicit upcast to a base class, and not a conversion constructor..

The simplified code:

```
for row in arr:
    for j, entry in enumerate(row):
        row[j] = int(entry)
```